# My form always tells users there's a problem

Tags: php, html, forms, email, recaptcha

I'm a total PHP idiot so I'm re-using some PHP code that works in another site of mine to get an email when visitors use an HTML form. Although all the HTML and PHP code looks properly matched to me, submitting a form always triggers the *errorurl*.
I suspect the recaptcha could be the problem, as the recaptcha dashboard tells me there's been no usage. Can someone help this journalist-turned-unwilling-developer? Thank you in advance.

Claudio

---

Here's the HTML form:

```
<form action="contactus.php" method="post" name="contact_form" target="_self" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm"><label for="yourname">Your first name<strong>*</strong></label>
            <input autofocus required type="text" id="yourname" class="form-control" accesskey="n" tabindex="1" placeholder="please enter your given name"></div>

            <div class="col-sm"><label for="yoursurname">Your family name<strong>*</strong></label>
            <input autofocus required type="text" id="yoursurname" class="form-control" accesskey="s" tabindex="2" placeholder="please enter your family name"></div>


            <div class="col-sm"><label for="yourmobile">Your mobile<strong>*</strong></label><input required maxlength="10" type="tel" id="yourmobile" class="form-control" accesskey="m" tabindex="3" placeholder="enter your mobile, no spaces or prefix"></div>
          </div>
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm"><label for="youremail">Your email<strong>*</strong></label>
            <input required type="email" id="youremail" class="form-control" accesskey="e" tabindex="4" placeholder="please enter your email"></div>
            <div class="col-sm">
            <label for="yourcompany">Your Company</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yourcompany" accesskey="c" tabindex="5" placeholder="Your Company">
          <small id="emailHelp1" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your details with anyone else.</small> </div></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="healthfund">Your comments<strong>*</strong></label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="healthfund" rows="5" tabindex="6" placeholder="Write away, no tight limits!"></textarea>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group"><label for>Please reassure us that you are human... </label><br>
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfKAcwUAAAAAAzIKAGlduOulkTw5PU7cuFzdUst"></div>
            <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg float-right ml-4" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="7" value="OK" /><input class="btn bg-danger btn-lg float-right" name="cancel" type="button" tabindex="8" value="Cancel" onClick="javascript:history.go(-1)"/></div>

      </form>
```

and this is the PHP file:

```
<?php
$mailto = 'claudioparoli@gmail.com' ;
$subject = "contact" ;
$formurl = "contactus.html" ;
$errorurl = "contacterror.html" ;
$thankyouurl = "contactthankyou.html" ;

$yourname_is_required = 1;
$yoursurname_is_required = 1;
$yourmobile_is_required = 1;
$youremail_is_required = 1;
$yourcompany_is_required = 0;
$comments_is_required = 1;
$uself = 1;
$use_envsender = 0;
$use_sendmailfrom = 0;
$use_webmaster_email_for_from = 0;
$use_utf8 = 1;
$my_recaptcha_private_key = '' ;

// -------------------- END OF CONFIGURABLE SECTION ---------------

$headersep = (!isset( $uself ) || ($uself == 0)) ? "\r\n" : "\n" ;
$content_type = (!isset( $use_utf8 ) || ($use_utf8 == 0)) ? 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' : 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' ;
if (!isset( $use_envsender )) { $use_envsender = 0 ; }
if (isset( $use_sendmailfrom ) && $use_sendmailfrom) {
    ini_set( 'sendmail_from', $mailto );
}
$envsender = "-f$mailto" ;
$yourname = (isset($_POST['yourname']))? $_POST['yourname'] : $_POST['yourname'] ;
$yoursurname = $_POST['yoursurname'];
$yourmobile = $_POST['yourmobile'] ;
$youremail = $_POST['youremail'] ;
$yourcompany = $_POST['yourcompany'] ;
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$http_referrer = getenv( "HTTP_REFERER" );

if (!isset($_POST['youremail'])) {
    header( "Location: $formurl" );
    exit ;
}
if (($youremail_is_required && (empty($youremail) || !preg_match('/@/', $youremail))) || ($yourname_is_required && empty($yourname)) || ($yoursurname_is_required && empty($yoursurname)) || ($yourmobile_is_required && empty($yourmobile)) || ($yourcompany_is_required && empty($yourcompany)) || ($comments_is_required && empty($comments))) {
header( "Location: $errorurl" );
exit ;
}
if ( preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $yourname ) || preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $youremail ) ) {
header( "Location: $errorurl" );
exit ;
}

if (strlen( $my_recaptcha_private_key )) {
    require_once( '../../edge/recaptchalib.php' );
   $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ( $my_recaptcha_private_key, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'], $_POST['recaptcha_response_field'] );
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        header( "Location: $errorurl" );
        exit ;
    }
}
if (empty($youremail)) {
    $youremail = $mailto ;
}
$fromemail = (!isset( $use_webmaster_email_for_from ) || ($use_webmaster_email_for_from == 0)) ? $email : $mailto ;

if (function_exists( 'get_magic_quotes_gpc' ) && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $details = stripslashes( $details );
}

$messageproper =
    "This message was sent from:\n" .
    "$http_referrer\n" .

"-------------------THE SENDER-----------------------\n\n" .

    "name of sender: $yourname\n" .
    "surname of sender: $yoursurname\n" .
    "mobile of sender: $yourmobile\n" .
    "email of sender: $youremail\n" .
    "company of sender: $yourcompany\n" .
    "comments by sender: $comments\n\n" .

    "\n\n------------------------------------------\n" ;

$headers =
    "From: \"$yourname\" <$youremail>" . $headersep . "Reply-To: \"$yourname\" <$youremail>" . $headersep . "X-Mailer: chfeedback.php 2.15.0" .
    $headersep . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $headersep . $content_type ;

if ($use_envsender) {
    mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, $headers, $envsender );
}
else {
    mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, $headers );
}
header( "Location: $thankyouurl" );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a debugger and step through the code to see which of your validations is redirecting to the error page.
If you don't have a debugger installed, then use error_log before each redirect with some text to tell you which validation was hit. Look in the log for your messages.

Something like

```
if (($youremail_is_required && (empty($youremail) || !preg_match('/@/', $youremail))) || ($yourname_is_required && empty($yourname)) || ($yoursurname_is_required && empty($yoursurname)) || ($yourmobile_is_required && empty($yourmobile)) || ($yourcompany_is_required && empty($yourcompany)) || ($comments_is_required && empty($comments))) {
error_log("email is required. youremail_is_required: $youremail_is_required youremail: $youremail your_username_is_required: $your_username_is_required yourusername: $yourusername");
header( "Location: $errorurl" );
exit ;
}
```